# Node's module.exports comes back as an empty object

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, require

I'm trying to build some utility modules for a grunt build process. Apparently I'm confused on how the module system works, but here is what I have (leaving out function logic since it's irrelevant):

```
var modifiers = {
    task: function(grunt){
       //logic...
    }
}

var modify = function(grunt){ 
    modifiers.task();
}

module.exports = {
    modify: modify
};
```

And then from a calling file:

```
var modifiers = require('./modifiers');

// later in file....
grunt.log.writeln(JSON.stringify(modifiers)); //outputs: {}
```

So the log call outputs an empty object. Calling modifiers.modify gives an error:

`Warning: modifiers.modify is not a function`

Am I completely missing how module.exports works? I am using it in other files to export functions but I really need the whole private-variable semantic here.

I've also tried setting module.exports to a self-calling function that returns an object, along with other stuff -- to no avail. How do I get it to just return the modifiers object? It needs to be extensible, thus me wanting to return an object.

Any help would be huge. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON.stringify()` does not serialize function properties so since your `modifiers` object only has a single property that is a function, `JSON.stringify()` shows an empty object.

A test like:

```
console.log(modifiers);
```

or

```
console.log(modifiers.modify);
```

will show what you expect if your module is working properly.

If calling `modifiers.modify()` creates an error, then you must have an error loading your `./modifiers` module and your console should show some sort of error when loading it.

Comment: Thanks. Also, I had referenced the exported obejct incorrectly in the calling file. Posting this helped me see that.

Comment: Didn't know that about JSON.stringify, which is good to know. I checked the MDN docs and you're totally right. Thanks a lot! Will accept once it lets me (Have to wait like 10 minutes)...